# Tooltip or pop over for tablet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablet

I am working on a web app that asks 10 questions, each question carries 3 possible answers. What I need for each  answer is a tool tip or pop over that displays a direction for each answer. I have tried using tool tips and pop overs so far, but while the tip is displayed, it requires two clicks to complete the action. 
Can I do this in one tap, as I need to minimize the amount of taps on the screen. Is there any javascript, or jquery that can solve this problem? Here is  the code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.radio-inline').tooltip({title: "Indicated!", animation: true}); 

});
</script>
       <tr>
       <td class="form-group col-md-6">Is there an indication for the drug?</td>

       <td id="Indication" class="form-group col-md-6">




           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Indicated"><input type="radio" name="indication" id="a1" value="0" <?php echo $a1; ?> required>A</input></p>
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Marginally Indicated"><input type="radio" name="indication" id="a2" value="0" <?php echo $a2; ?> required>B</input></p>
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Not Indicated"><input type="radio" name="indication" id="a3" value="3" <?php echo $a3; ?> required>C</input></p>

       </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td class="form-group col-md-6">Is the medication effective for the condition?</td>
       <td  id="Effectiveness" class="form-group col-md-6">
            <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Effective"><input type="radio" name="effective" id="b1" value="0" <?php echo $b1; ?> required>A</input></p>
            <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Marginally Effective"><input type="radio" name="effective" id="b2" value="0" <?php echo $b2; ?> required>B</input></p>
            <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ineffective"><input type="radio" name="effective" id="b3" value="3" <?php echo $b3; ?> required>C</input></p>
       </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td class="form-group col-md-6">Is the dosage correct?</td>
       <td class="form-group col-md-6">
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Correct"><input type="radio" name="correctdose" id="c1" value="0" <?php echo $c1; ?> required>A</input></p>
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Marginally Correct"><input type="radio" name="correctdose" id="c2" value="0" <?php echo $c2; ?> required>B</input></p>
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Incorrect"><input type="radio" name="correctdose" id="c3" value="2" <?php echo $c3; ?> required>C</input></p>
       </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td class="form-group col-md-6"> Are the directions correct? </td>
       <td class="form-group col-md-6">
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Correct"><input type="radio" name="correctdir" id="d1" value="0" <?php echo $d1; ?> required>A</input></p>
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Marginally Correct"><input type="radio" name="correctdir" id="d2" value="0" <?php echo $d2; ?> required>B</input></p>
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Incorrect"><input type="radio" name="correctdir" id="d3" value="2" <?php echo $d3; ?> required>C</input></p>
       </td>
       </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want tooltips that are triggered when you hover over them, but you don't get hover actions on tablets (unless you are using a mouse), so this is not possible. So in order to prevent the user from having to click twice on the input, I would suggest some sort of help icon next to the input that they can touch to trigger the tooltip.

Comment: could you give me an example? The only difficulty is that there are multiple questions and multiple answers, so  that would be a lot of answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `title` attribute of `HTML` elements.

It shows when you `hover` on the elements.

Check out this [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/1ds21vax/1/).

See the following snippets. (Hover on the text and see different messages)

```html
<span title='This is a greeting'>Hello</span>
<br>
<div title='Do you know what this is?'>Run for your life</div>
```

Comment: It is a part of basic `HTML`. So it will work on everything that supports `HTML`.

Comment: Could you please adapt my code just so I know where to make the changes please, thank you so much

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/1ds21vax/1/). I used `JavaScript` because it would be easier for you to update the code using JavaScript as you have too many elements to change.